# How to find the keykode for a specific key (Fn) with JIntellitype (Java)

Tags: java, keycode, awtrobot, keystroke, jintellitype

I want the Robot class in java to simulate a key combination <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. I have added the Jintellitype library to my project but in the list of keycodes that JIntellitype comes with i still cannot seem to find the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

My question is how can I find what the key code for that specific key is?

Comment: That might not possible. Depending on your Laptop, Fn keys might be handled in the EC (embedded controller) already and not be visible to the operating system. Furthermore there is no standard regarding how these keys are communicated if they are visible to the operating system.